# What is the correct definition of Minkowski distance

Tags: clustering

I'm really confused. In a book [ISBN: 978-0-470-27680-8](http://www.wiley-vch.de/publish/en/books/bySubjectEE00/bySubSubjectEE70/0-470-27680-0/?sID=h1tjs4msm9be2umsaod861gql5) is written:

> The Euclidean distance can be generalized as a special case of a family of
>   metrics, called Minkowski distance or L p norm, defined as,
>   $$
> D(\mathbf{x}_i,{\mathbf x}_j)=\left(\sum_{l=1}^d |x_{il}-x_{jl}|^{1/p}\right)^p \tag{1}
> $$

Is it correct? In other sources Minkowski distance is defined as:

> $$
> \left( \color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^n} |x_{i}-y_{i}|^p\right)^{1/p} \tag{2}
> $$

Which one is correct? (notice to powers)

---

**J.D.'s edit:** The highlighted red part was missing from a previous edit.. Originally, OP included the following two images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please cite the book by its authors and title. ISBN numbers are not designed to replace bibliogrphic information and in fact suck at that!

Comment: Might be that: [Xu, Rui / Wunsch, Don, *Clustering*](http://www.wiley-vch.de/publish/en/books/bySubjectEE00/bySubSubjectEE70/0-470-27680-0/?sID=h1tjs4msm9be2umsaod861gql5)

Comment: I think it's about similarity (1st formula) and dissimilarity (2nd formula) measures.

Comment: Here http://www.isbnsearch.org/isbn/9780470276808

Comment: Well, the wiki page on [Minkowski_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Minkowski_distance&oldid=479889579) doesn't have references.

Comment: @J.D., it is true that sufficient work *will* find relevant bibliographic data from an ISBN number... but I will put little energy in answering questions into which the asker himself has not put the energy enough to make it easy for me to know what book he is talking about!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A metric (or distance) and a norm are two different things. You can use a norm to define a metric, but not necessarily the other way around. The Minkowski metric is the metric induced by the $L_p$ norm, that is, the metric in which the distance between two vectors is the norm of their difference.

Both of these formulas describe the same family of metrics, since $p\to1/p$ transforms from one to the other. So if your question is "which of these two expressions describes the family of Minkowski metrics", the answer is both. However, if the question is "which of them gives the metric induced by the $L_p$ norm", it's the second one,

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|^p\right)^{1/p}\;.$$

You can remember that by remembering that $L_2$ is the standard Euclidean norm, in which the exponent $2$ is on the inside and the exponent $1/2$ is on the outside.

Comment: What is deference between norm and metric, in that book is mentioned:"Perhaps the most commonly used distance measure is the Euclidean distance,
also known as L 2 norm, represented ..." but in euclidean distance D(0,4) for formula of book is equal to  root(32)   but for wikipedia formula it is equal to 16

Comment: @Reza: You'll have to point out what part of the answers you've already received you don't understand; otherwise there's no point in adding yet another one. Both Emre's answer and mine describe the difference between a norm and a metric as clearly as I can describe it; unless you say what part of that is unclear to you, there's nothing more I can say. Your book is simply wrong in conflating a distance and a norm.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about the difference between a metric and a norm:

A norm and a metric are two related but different things. Generally speaking, a norm is a more "vector space" concept than metrics.

A norm assigns value to a **SINGLE** vectors (its length) in a vector space, while metric assigns value to **TWO** elements (their distance) in a metric space (which is not necessarily a vector space). Of course, in a vector space, a metric system can always be induced from a norm system by defining ||x-y|| as d(x,y).

Also, a norm must have Positive Homogeneity and Translation Invariance, both of which come quite naturally for a vector space, while a metric doesn't need to.

Not sure if this answers your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is a compliant

Answer (score 1):

The Euclidean distance is the $L^2$ norm of the difference vector, and thus a special case as claimed. The first definition is correct; I can't read the second one.. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Both are (almost) right.  And they say the same thing.  Just notation adapted to the particular problem.

In

> $$
> D(\mathbf{x}_i,{\mathbf x}_j)=\left(\sum_{l=1}^d |x_{il}-x_{jl}|^{1/p}\right)^p \tag{1}
> $$

we have points ${\mathbf x}_i$ and ${\mathbf x}_j$ in $d$-space, where
${\mathbf x}_i$ has coordinates $x_{i1},\dots,x_{id}$ and
${\mathbf x}_j$ has coordinates $x_{j1},\dots,x_{jd}$

But in fact this one should be
$$
D(\mathbf{x}_i,{\mathbf x}_j)=\left(\sum_{l=1}^d |x_{il}-x_{jl}|^{p}\right)^{1/p}
$$
(are you sure you copied (1) correctly?)

In

> $$
> \left( {\sum_{i=1}^n} |x_{i}-y_{i}|^p\right)^{1/p} \tag{2}
> $$

we have points $x$ and $y$ in $n$-space, where $x$ has coordinates $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $y$ has coordinates $y_1,\dots,y_n$.